# Getting error: Unable to parse POM

Tags: java, maven, selenium, jenkins, automated-tests

While  building a Maven project in Jenkins, I am getting below error. Can you provide steps to solve this error?

```
Building in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\JenkinProject
Unpacking https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/apache-maven/3.5.3/apache-maven-3.5.3-bin.zip to C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\tools\hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation\TestMaven on Jenkins
ERROR: Failed to parse POMs
java.io.IOException: Failed to rename C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\tools\hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation\TestMaven\apache-maven-3.5.3 to C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\tools\hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation\TestMaven\apache-maven-3.5.3.__rename
    at hudson.FilePath$29.invoke(FilePath.java:2107)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: What's the mvn command you used? And is your pom.xml file is located where you ran the program?

Comment: I used  clean install  .... buiding from jenkins not from cmd

Comment: is your pom.xml file is located where you ran the program? – Where shall I keep it and how

Comment: please run go to terminal (on linux) or cmd (windows), navigate to the project folder where the pom.xml located and run 'mvn clean install', then post the output

Comment: Project is building successfully via maven... i am facing this issue while building project via jenkins

Comment: Is https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-33884 making any help?

Comment: Not getting how to do?

Comment: even after disabling antivirus... faced same error

Comment: Is your Jenkins windows slave use JNLP? what user is logged in?

Comment: I am new to jenkins...how to check it

Comment: Which machine is running the job? Is it master or slave?

Comment: its Master machine

Comment: My suggestion for you: work with VMware or virtualbox to set up ubuntu virtual machine. Afterwards, set this machine as Jenkins slave for your Jenkins server. Then try to run the job on this Linux slave. It should be much more simple then debugging this security issue on your windows master.

Comment: Will try with above approach